# 404 Not Found when viewing product detail page after customer logging in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Without logging in, I can see my product on the product page, but after logging in it shows a 404. I can see the product in category view, but when I click on the product, it shows a 404.

Comment: Do you have any customer group restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-indexing the indexers using the Magento 2 CLI Command.

Login to your server via SSH and navigate to the root of your Magento 2 directory. Now, run the following CLI command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If you want to be sure that NO cache is involved and everything is clean enough, you can run all the following Magento 2 CLI Commands in the same order:

```
rm -Rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: thanks fayyaz for your reply,but its not work for me